# Blazor IdentityServer Authenthentication

Tags: asp.net, blazor, identityserver4

Currently I have three separate servers. Client on :5001, API on :5002 and IdentityServer on :5003. I can athenticate my Blazor pages using `@attribute [Authorize]` but when I call the API I get a 401 error. If I past the token_id into postman and make a request to the API server it authenticates. If I make a request from my Blazor client it fails. I have whitelisted CORS to rule out that being the issue. If I remove the Audience check on the api with:

```
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
```

It works

Client program.cs

```
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("api")
                .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => 
                {
                    var handler = sp.GetService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
                        .ConfigureHandler(
                            authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://localhost:5002" },
                            scopes: new[] { "coredesk" });
                    return handler;
                });
            
            builder.Services.AddScoped(
                sp => sp.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("api"));
            
            builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("oidc", options.ProviderOptions);
            });
```

Client appsettings.json

```
{
  "oidc": {
    "Authority": "https://localhost:5003/",
    "ClientId": "coredesk",
    "DefaultScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "coredesk"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "/",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
}
```

API Startup.cs

```
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5003";
                    options.Audience = "coredesk";
                });
```

IdentityServer Config.cs

```
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            };
        
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis =>
            new ApiResource[]
            {
                new ApiResource("coredesk", "CoreDesk API")
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new ApiScope[]
            {
                new ApiScope("coredesk"),
            };

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[]
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "coredesk",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://localhost:5001", "https://localhost:5002" },
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "coredesk" },
                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/" },
                    Enabled = true
                },
            };
```

Comment: What does the WWW-Authenticate response header say when you get the 401 error? Sample error can look like this:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Comment: If i remove the Authorize attribute in the api and run the debugger. The Microsoft documentation and the guide I followed don't show you having to add the Token to the header. I assumed this would be so you are not storing the token within the browser https://medium.com/@marcodesanctis2/securing-blazor-webassembly-with-identity-server-4-ee44aa1687ef

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the source code for [AddJwtBearer](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs) you find this part:

```
                // If no authorization header found, nothing to process further
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization))
                {
                    return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
                }

                if (authorization.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    token = authorization.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
                }

                // If no token found, no further work possible
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
                }
```

this shows that by default (without customization) it requires the token to be provided in the Authorization header, like this:

```
GET /api/payments HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7001
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIYwA...
```

to further debug, I would remove the authorize attribute and then put a breakpoint in one of the action method and examine what the ClaimsPrincipal user object contains.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: It's definitely getting the token. I just tried removing the Audience check on the API and it works. I'm pretty sure I am not missing the coredesk scope from anywhere.

Comment: What does the WWW-Authenticate header say? you can also look at the logs from the API, Kestrel does provide plenty of good logs.

Comment: Do also take a look at this blog post https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/